# Adding name label and date label for JSQMessages

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a topLabel to the JSQMessageCollectionViewCell and am implementing the correct method, but nothing is showing up. Here is my code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {

    let msg: JSQMessage = self.JSQmessages[indexPath.item]
    if (msg.senderId != self.senderId) {

        return NSAttributedString(string: "Tester")
    }
    else {
        return NSAttributedString(string: senderDisplayName)
    }

}
```

Additionally, I am trying to add the date label by tapping on a given message collection cell. How should I go about doing this? I am adding an NSDate as part of each JSQMessage.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a height for the top label by implementing:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In order to show the label on tap, you'll need to store the selected `indexPath`, and return a height for that `indexPath` in the above method.